# Computing the electric potential generated by a current density across media with different conductivities

Tags: voltage, electromagnetism, conductivity, resistivity

Model: a right cylinder composed three layers of conductive media. The is a disk of unit charge density in the center of the cylinder. The disk radius is equal to the cylinder radius. The outer layers have effectively infinite length. I have numerically computed the electric potential at sampled distances from the disk, see below. 
[image: Potential over space for two models]

The solid blue trace represents my result for the model as described. The dashed red trace is my result if I set all three media conductivities to be equal to the central medium's conductivity. The dotted black lines show the boundaries between media.

Does this look correct?

My simple linear intuition is that the conductivities of the outer layers should not affect the potential in the inner layers due to a vague notion of causality, hence the red and blue traces are overlapping in that region.

However, my suspicion is that my intuition does not apply to electrostatics, and that the outer conductivities somehow "pull" on the inner layer rather than everything propagating outward.

If my suspicions are correct, how to I compute the potential correctly?

My methods are outlined [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/307571/how-to-compute-electrostatic-forward-in-a-cylinder-with-variable-conductivity).

Thank you.

Edit:

Thank you so much @Janka. The intuition is that the model boils down to resistors in series. Becuase the effects of resistors in series sum linearly, the conductivity layers cannot affect each other, as this would yield non-linear summation, assuming a steady state.

Comment: I think the reason why the blue and red line overlap in the middle region might be due to the Gauss Theorem : electric field only depends on charges inside.

Comment: A meta-questions for seeking help on this matter: is this sort of topic more under the purview of physics or electrical engineering? Also, this is not my primary field; at what level of expertise would one expect this model to be familiar, e.g. undergraduate, doctoral, post-doctoral? I assume (hope) that I am not covering new ground in electrostatics.

Comment: If its pure electrostatics and not to complicated, I think graduate in electrical engineering can understand. Once again, if your problem is pure electrostatics you should more use charge density instead of conductivity and solve it with Poisson equation. In this case for physical intuition Gauss theorem (which is the integral version of Poisson equation) gives good insights.

Comment: Is it a conductor or an insulator or both? How is it possible to prevent discharge?  Where is your 0V reference?  Why is there no polarity?  What does the dotted line represent?  Is there any charge transfer?

Comment: No special rules for electrostatics. The results are the same as for a steady-state current flow, meaning, you can replace charge by current and all your results stay the same. Boundaries behave special as soon your current flow (or charge) changes, because they act as capacitors, but for steady-state they are nonexisting.

Comment: re:@Tony (1) it is 3 concatenated conductors. (2) metabolic energy is being spent maintaining the charge density. (3) Very far away in a medium with identical properties as the probe electrode but with no charge density. (4) The charge density is monopolar (5) boundaries between the conductors (6) I'm not sure what you mean, but the charge density is physically fixed.

Comment: re:@Janka, I take your comment to mean that you think the diagram looks correct. Does shunting play any role here?

Comment: Yes, your diagram looks familiar for a cylinder. All the curve form results from geometry with the conductive area increasing with r and thus, the resistance decreasing with 1/r. You are introspecting two concatenated resistors with a voltage probe. Play in your head with the one-dimensional case and you see how the simpler geometry leads you to a much simpler plot.

Comment: What do you mean by shunting? You only have one charge source, the corresponding charge sink is *far far away* so it doesn't matter. If you need another boundary somewhere at r=r2 to understand the influence of that charge think of it as residing on a perfectly conductive layer matching your geometry perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more digging, I think I have found that my original suspicions were correct. There is some non-linearity.

I created a 2d finite element method model that approximates my conditions at least qualitatively:

[image]

The subplot on the right is a cross-section taken from the y-center of the heat maps. This modeling result is backed up by the theory described [here](http://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.303/inhomog-notes.pdf).

I was assuming the simple case of $$ -c\nabla^2 u=f $$ which my system reduces to when the three layers are identical and c is scalar. But in my case I need, $$  -\nabla *(c\nabla u)=f $$ to account for the "scattered" terms.

I do not yet completely understand  the equations covered in this document, but I believe they are to key to this problem.